# Issue getting text from amazon.com

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am getting shipping text from amazon.com as in the picture below:

[image]

But the issue is i cannot get this text even though its shown on the site,not sure whats wrong in it example is this link.

[SAMPLE LINK 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AZD9YCC)

Not sure whats wrong in it, if you see the page source it wont have in it and still its showing on the page which is confusing me, for other this works fine and there are many more pages like this example.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above post is right, its loaded after the page, so the link you truely need is:

```
GET http://www.amazon.com/gp/twister/ajax/prefetch/184-8017667-8054405?json=1&sid=184-8017667-8054405&rid=0EY8R4VSQH90CGG2B8WB&parentAsin=B00AZD9YO0&qid=&sr=&asinList=B00AZD9YCC,B00AZD9YO0&productGroupID=health_and_beauty_display_on_website&merchantID=&smid=null&PowerBar=0&pfWrapFeatures=0&rps=0&_=1358853427426 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.amazon.com
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
Referer: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00AZD9YCC/?tag=stackoverfl08-20
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: x-wl-uid=12Rt0TTSfvFFeeEo/b9iO7gAvvtsw+sHdWjU1SmtKe3jzgy3Bnf5YM/gC+Zm2ZMG5bJiGZ2xkab0=; session-token=QMx3+akd/XUQe2V8GVUQ3fioq2STsxGQWCTw5AUILjVp5itgNLqGYps7hrRzzq2v0LoD8e0VjoC0EH+c8aZE0ybkSB4VNhfnGPLWyC/5s0yDboyQr9bsxEcuJzpSH5lS0xj9bvd6Rz6u195/PCt7G8W/9bPscFcGCOOczEh46FoQ0wM8/I+IZL/tsTtlCoS7WtomqeKvqgUxrqYqFrB0+cNbH0L2vg3Z3zLX45qER4i9LByiil/UeOeNtqtKnN0A; ubid-main=181-8869220-9587219; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=184-8017667-8054405; UserPref=ZQYGYZ6aqj9V1WCTNQfIBVHwrxWUiRBbtjYgpE662zHEbrcpva4uwDzapqUVUnEAv7+ZRaU6VjPKllub9eBfBEVyz+RPxbaEmIS3D9nkpoNciDxQuq8F4WFNYy8WKy4AzYftKT9qYMugJLXI2w7L9Jt6780u982A54mduTieZ7XvtM991yXd8WzHgADBGM6vnfjtkwaFeRcJ6jkFysNFob24qESWn1sN2mZT3YVgjfWBqb1X8Z3FZbNmZt4qp8ZEtjl0wXNhZRHlP6OZ3+HbabTWQKGoG1kRzJJ9YQAv4QMKP2zyQnI2/MJp/VohCMF+1kfimtGK8+azjZQClkezqjBdRTYQ6PFuOPB6sVJS1EIY0GGRZ4ugjr/ynWLQrxvO3LUOYDByWeF2GtH+WlscSpdZUaRrxGipc/Ze1nwhz+KyVBv4vnf4kJx93WjpbJbMu6PdOC1fiXg=; csm-hit=3949.77|
```

You will have to build the Get request using the ASIN number I believe and parse the response to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

It is present, but it's probably being loaded asynchronously after the page itself loads, hence it won't necessarily be visible via whatever method you're viewing the source with.

```
<span class="plusShippingText">
    &nbsp;+&nbsp;$4.02&nbsp;shipping
</span>
```

Comment: any way to get it for sure every time?